# How to get the number of elements in a JSON array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, encode

I'm getting `json_encode` data from controller. The resulting array is like:

```
[
  { "name": "aaa" },
  { "name": "bbb" },
  { "name": "ccc" }
]
```

How to get the number of elements in this array using JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: The newly-selected answer has nothing whatsoever to do with `json`. Please amend your question/title to remove all references to json if you wish to remain with that answer. Thank you. http://jsfiddle.net/wxbvbwtp/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always get array length by length property of an array.

Here is the reference from w3school:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_array.asp

Code:

```
<p>Click the button to create an array, then display it's length.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits.length;
    }
</script>
```

Try the working code in fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5arrc15d/

Hope it helps.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use `.length` property of array to get number of items in array.

```
var arr=[{"name":"aaa"},{"name":"bbb"},{"name":"ccc"}];
alert(arr.length)
```

Here in alert you will get number of items in array arr.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of elements in an array using `yourArray.length`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**.length**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property in order to get no of elements in an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = '[{"name":"aaa"},{"name":"bbb"},{"name":"ccc"}]';
var y = $.parseJSON(x);

alert( y.length );
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wxbvbwtp/)

---

Best references:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

http://www.w3fools.com/

---

Notes:

1. Var `x` is not an array, it is a string -- a json string.  Alerting `x.length` will return the length of the string, not the length of the array.
2. Var `y` has been parsed into a javascript array. `y.length` will return the number of items in the array.
3. You specifically asked about the length of a `json` array, so first you must parse the json into a javascript array.

[jsFiddle comparison](http://jsfiddle.net/wxbvbwtp/1/)

Comment: This too.. JSON.parse(array)